# How to Let subset compare to array

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have a data frame `data` with a column called `Number` that contains various numbers e.g. 1,2,..10. How can I create a subset frame from `data` containing only entries where for example numbers 2 5 8 are excluded. I tried:

```
data2 <- subset( data, Number != c( 2, 5, 8 ) )
```

This does not work and I get the following warning message: "Warning message:
In RecordingNo != c(4, 5) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

Hope anyone can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try for instance:
     `data2 <- subset( data, ! Number %in% c( 2, 5, 8 ) )`

Explanation: the %in% operator will compare Number element-wise with the exclusion set to produce a Boolean True/False for each element of the Number vector with the True values indicating where an element of the exclusion set is found. The ! operator is  logical "not" and therefore inverts the aforementioned Boolean vector to give us the subset condition we want.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: glad to be of assistance